# Не изменить ли требования к шапке вопроса?

Tags: предложение

Сайт малопосещаем именно из-за плохо сформулированных вопросов, имхо.

Просто замечательно, что "заголовок не может быть длиннее 150 символов": 150 - это много, прямо-таки раззудись, плечо, размахнись, рука. Но -

за редким (редчайшим) исключением, например когда в шапку выносится всё проблемное предложение и только в поле "основная часть" можно разжевать проблему и сомнения вкупе со своим взглядом на её решение,

вопрос обязан содержать ключевые слова, по которым он и будет гуглиться-яндекситься.

Примеры "правильного" вопроса:

[«На самом деле». Нужна ли запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)

[“Ни при чём” или “ни причём”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30109/%D0%9D%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC)

[Помогите определиться с порядком использования звёздочек в сносках](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450350/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

[Краткое прилагательное и наречие: как отличить?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34881/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C/34894#34894)

[Чем отличается шпион от разведчика?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450335/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

И - категорически не нужные сайту (хотя и, возможно, важные для вопрошателя) вопросы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Что такое “как” в этом предложении?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9643/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

[Помогите с пунктуацией в тексте](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437839/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5)

[Нужно ли “мол”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420285/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB)

[Помогите, пожалуйста, переписать предложение. Продемонстрируйте высокий стиль )](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450309/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C)

[Странная история](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450284/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Вот представим на минуточку, кто придёт за чужими запятыми или историей, даже и узрев их в поисковых системах. Да и в поиске по сайту...

Comment: Галина, а есть ли у вас конкретные идеи, которые стоит рассмотреть и, возможно, превратить в новые требования?

Comment: Да, и я их изложила здесь: *Вопрос обязан содержать ключевые слова, по которым он и будет гуглиться-яндекситься* - и предложены пять примеров  "правильного" вопроса в противовес десятку "неправильных", работающих только и исключительно на вопрошателя.

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I am wrong but the status-review tag seems to be misused here? This feels like a community decision and not one that needs oversight from the community management team. Please let me know if I am understanding this incorrectly.

Comment: @SpencerG true. Sorry, some mistake happened. It was so long ago...

Answer (score 1):

Я сталкиваюсь с другой проблемой: часто изложения вопроса в заголовке вопроса достаточно, из-за чего возникают проблемы с тем, то писать в основном поле. Суть же уже изложена. Дублировать? А зачем? Оттого и возникают невнятные заголовки, чтобы было, что написать на странице.

По самой теме: если убрать все вопросы про "помогите расставить запятые", то чем вообще займётся сайт и кто его будет посещать? Три с половиной человека? Я сам здесь бываю именно для решения частных задач. И, к слову, никогда не задумывал пускаться по страницам в поисках интересных заголовков в архиве. Большинство вопросов решаются в первые дни, после того, как заданы. Смысла в подсказках для археологов форума не вижу. Даже если установить требование к вопросу следующим образом: "Как расставить запятые в предложении (это человек, который)", он всё равно никому не нужен будет в поиске яндекса.

Для поиска  по конкретным темам есть метки, тут вам и этимология, и фразеологизмы, и куча всего на любой вкус.

Что касается тем вроде "“Ни при чём” или “ни причём”?" и "Краткое прилагательное и наречие: как отличить?", то они никому не нужны. Если человек так формулирует вопрос, то он будет искать конкретное правило. И найдёт! Форум ему не нужен, ибо сюда приводят именно частные ситуации, когда человек хочет разобраться в конкретной ситуации, а не думать, подходит ли общее правило к его ситуации или же нет.

А вот эти все демагогии про "ненужные сайту" вопросы не нужны. Сайт существует для посетителей и только благодаря им. Здесь и без того немало требований, которые отпугивают новичков: регистрация, свой вариант ответа, не делаем Д/З, перепишите слишком длинный вопрос, написали не в то поле, у вас недостаточно рейтинга и т.д. Давайте ещё введите требования к заголовкам, и скоро тут в людный день больше четырёх пользователей не будет.